# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\\ANONYMOUS LOGON' when accessing sql server from a wcf service with impersonation

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wcf, wcf-security

I have a very specific problem with a WCF service I'm using:

I have an ASP.NET page with 2 dropdowns:

- The first one is populated from the ASP.NET code behind.
- The other one is populated from a WCF service via a jQuery ajax call.

Both of them use impersonation to go to the SQL Server database as the logged in user.
This works well with all our customers, except for 1 environment.
There I'm getting the following exception when trying to call the database from the WCF service:

```
"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.","StackTrace":"   
                at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)\u000d\u000a   
                at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)\u000d\u000a   
                at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)\u000d\u000a   
                at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)\u000d\u000a   
                at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)\u000d\u000a 
...
```

It seems that for some reason the WCF service is using the anonymous account to access the database, although the call from the ASP.NET code behind still works as expected and uses the expected account to access the database.
The connection string uses `Integrated Security=SSPI`.
It must be some environment specific configuration we are missing, but I can't see what exactly as the delegation and impersonation works directly from ASP.NET.

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

**EDIT:**
The system.servicemodel section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceWebBindingName">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>     
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>     
    <behavior name="HistoryReportingEndpointBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HistoryReportingServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="HistoryReportingServiceBehavior" name="ServiceLibrary.HistoryReporting">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="HistoryReportingEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceWebBindingName" name="HistoryReportingWebEndPoint" contract="ServiceLibrary.IHistoryReporting" />
  </service>    
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an explicit SQL Connection from the WCF service to SQL? Are they on the same box?

Comment: The connection has to be made with the logged in Windows account.
The SQL server is on another machine.

Comment: OK, make the WCF service run under a network account that has rights to the SQL server. Either that, or add the Windows account you're using to run the WCF to the logins on the SQL Server. 

Right now, WCF is running under NT\Anon because that's the default from the way you set it up (I'm guessing under IIS), but that account doesn't have rights to SQL on the other machine. So you need to change the account WCF runs under to something SQL will accept.

Comment: The Windows account can log in on the SQL Server and it is also used from the ASP.NET code.
Both WCF service and ASP.NET are in the same project, so aren't there running under the same user account then?

Comment: Are you just running the WCF as an executable, or is it fronted by IIS? I ask because that NT\Anon is the default ID under which IIS runs web services.

Comment: It is fronted by IIS.

Comment: Is Anonymous Authentication disabled on the problem IIS?

Comment: Also, could yopu post the service model part of your web.config?

Comment: I added it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is likely because the IIS Application Pool that your web application is using is running under an account that doesn't have SQL Server privileges. Change the Application Pool Account to one that can access SQL Server and the problem should go away.